# EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Trouble connecting Hadoop to Elasticsearch

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, databricks, elasticsearch-hadoop

I'm using Databrics to run my Spark application, and I'm trying to use `elasticsearch-hadoop` to build a connection with Elasticsearch.

After configuring a peering connection between my Databricks VPC and my Elasticsearch VPC, I can finally get the two to talk to each other. It looks like this:

```
%sh 
nc -vz [endpoint_to_elasticsearch].es.amazonaws.com 443
> [endpoint_to_elasticsearch].es.amazonaws.com 443 (https) open
```

which shows me that they are connected, great!

But the ultimate test nevertheless fails. Here is what I try to run:

```
%scala
val df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM test_data")
df.write
  .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
  .option("es.nodes.wan.only","true")
  .option("es.port","443")
  .option("es.net.ssl","true")
  .option("es.nodes", "[endpoint_to_elasticsearch]")
  .mode("Overwrite")
  .save("test_index/test_type")
```

The df is simply this:

```
df:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame = [field1: string]
+------+
|field1|
+------+
|  DS&S|
+------+
```

But the error I get is a pernicious one:

```
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot detect ES version - typically this happens if the network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only'.
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverClusterInfo(InitializationUtils.java:340)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.cfg$lzycompute(DefaultSource.scala:225)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.cfg(DefaultSource.scala:223)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.insert(DefaultSource.scala:603)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:292)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:235)
    at linef15e9c33e51e4c34a4649c4ec822a09d31.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-131822574348522:9)
    at linef15e9c33e51e4c34a4649c4ec822a09d31.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-131822574348522:55)
    at linef15e9c33e51e4c34a4649c4ec822a09d31.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-131822574348522:57)
    at linef15e9c33e51e4c34a4649c4ec822a09d31.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-131822574348522:59)
    at linef15e9c33e51e4c34a4649c4ec822a09d31.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-131822574348522:61)
    at linef15e9c33e51e4c34a4649c4ec822a09d31.$read$$iw.<init>(command-131822574348522:63)
    at linef15e9c33e51e4c34a4649c4ec822a09d31.$read.<init>(command-131822574348522:65)
    at linef15e9c33e51e4c34a4649c4ec822a09d31.$read$.<init>(command-131822574348522:69)
    at linef15e9c33e51e4c34a4649c4ec822a09d31.$read$.<clinit>(command-131822574348522)
    at linef15e9c33e51e4c34a4649c4ec822a09d31.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<notebook>:7)
    at linef15e9c33e51e4c34a4649c4ec822a09d31.$eval$.$print(<notebook>:6)
    at linef15e9c33e51e4c34a4649c4ec822a09d31.$eval.$print(<notebook>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:793)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1054)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:645)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:644)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:644)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:576)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:572)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.execute(DriverILoop.scala:215)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:197)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:197)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:197)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.trapExit(DriverLocal.scala:700)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExit$.apply(DriverLocal.scala:653)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.repl(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:197)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:386)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:363)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:235)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:230)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:49)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:272)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:49)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:363)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:639)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:485)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:597)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:390)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:337)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:219)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: null
null
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.checkResponse(RestClient.java:477)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:434)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:428)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:388)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:392)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.get(RestClient.java:168)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.mainInfo(RestClient.java:745)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverClusterInfo(InitializationUtils.java:330)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.cfg$lzycompute(DefaultSource.scala:225)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.cfg(DefaultSource.scala:223)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.insert(DefaultSource.scala:603)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:292)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:235)
    at linef15e9c33e51e4c34a4649c4ec822a09d31.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-131822574348522:9)
    at linef15e9c33e51e4c34a4649c4ec822a09d31.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-131822574348522:55)
    at linef15e9c33e51e4c34a4649c4ec822a09d31.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-131822574348522:57)
    at linef15e9c33e51e4c34a4649c4ec822a09d31.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-131822574348522:59)
    at linef15e9c33e51e4c34a4649c4ec822a09d31.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-131822574348522:61)
    at linef15e9c33e51e4c34a4649c4ec822a09d31.$read$$iw.<init>(command-131822574348522:63)
    at linef15e9c33e51e4c34a4649c4ec822a09d31.$read.<init>(command-131822574348522:65)
    at linef15e9c33e51e4c34a4649c4ec822a09d31.$read$.<init>(command-131822574348522:69)
    at linef15e9c33e51e4c34a4649c4ec822a09d31.$read$.<clinit>(command-131822574348522)
    at linef15e9c33e51e4c34a4649c4ec822a09d31.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<notebook>:7)
    at linef15e9c33e51e4c34a4649c4ec822a09d31.$eval$.$print(<notebook>:6)
    at linef15e9c33e51e4c34a4649c4ec822a09d31.$eval.$print(<notebook>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:793)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1054)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:645)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:644)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:644)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:576)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:572)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.execute(DriverILoop.scala:215)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:197)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:197)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:197)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.trapExit(DriverLocal.scala:700)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExit$.apply(DriverLocal.scala:653)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.repl(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:197)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:386)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:363)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:235)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:230)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:49)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:272)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:49)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:363)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:639)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:485)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:597)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:390)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:337)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:219)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

At first I thought this has to do with a version error, but I'm struggling to find the mismatch.

I'm running:

- AWS Elasticsearch - 7.1
- Databricks - 6.1 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.4, Scala 2.11)
- elasticsearch-hadoop - elasticsearch_spark_20_2_11_7_5_2.jar

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try port 9243 which is the default ES https port : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-enterprise/current/ece-connect.html

If it is not works, You can try to use socat command to forward your local port to your remote port:

```
socat tcp-listen:443,fork tcp:[endpoint_to_elasticsearch]:443 &
```